# List all websockets and log latency

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

1) Is there a way to list all connects websockets? I want to list theirs on a html page to admin propose. 
2) Is there a way to log latency? maybe with some kind of instrumentation on heartbeat... ?

Another things is, I want to have my some kind of track on websockets (like presence, I know that phoenix has one). It is easy with Agent/GenServer, but if it fail and restart, how get connects sockets again ?

thanks!

Comment: By sockets you mean websockets?

Comment: yes. all websocket on a channel